# How can I manage Kafka connect schema errors?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using kafka connect (confluent distribution) to connect an mqtt broker to a kafka topic (https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/source/mqtt.html), but when a message arrives and it isn't conform to the expected schema, the connector stops!

How can I prevent this from happening?

I'd like also to manage the error and for example keep track of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a ready made connector, you need to satisfy the proper schema. If any error occurs it will stop the connector. So, best way is to identify the schema error based on error message.

If its impossible to use the existing connector, create one for your own which could satisfy your need.